# Trigonometric identities: need a simple product form

Tags: trigonometry

Is there is a simple product form for $\cos(at) + \cos(bt+\alpha)$??

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use that $$\cos(X)+\cos(Y)=2\cos\left(\frac{X+Y}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{X-Y}{2}\right).$$

Take $X=at$ and $Y=bt+\alpha$. Hence,

$$\cos(at)+\cos(bt+\alpha)=2\cos\left(\frac{at+bt+\alpha}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{at-bt-\alpha}{2}\right).$$